# Why modern cellphones do not have an externally visible antenna?

Tags: antenna, cellphone

Old phones had either a fixed antenna inside a housing which was externally visible, or a retractable antenna, which was visible when used. I'm assuming this was needed to obtain a certain total length.

In modern cellphones all the antennas are inside the case. The height dimension of older cellphones was similar to current modern cellphones (smartphones). Why now externally visible antennas are not needed?

Comment: the RF changed as circuits got better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: external antennas are unattractive to the user. The consumer drives the market, and these days, consumers want thinner, lighter, faster, etc. This is actually a huge problem for antennas because the physics are fundamentally limiting.

Most antennas in cell phones are some sort of variant of a PIFA (planar inverted-F antenna). Antenna-Theory has some cool articles on [PIFAs](http://www.antenna-theory.com/antennas/aperture/ifa.php) and the now-famous [iPhone 4 antenna](http://www.antenna-theory.com/antennas/aperture/ifa.php). PIFAs are fairly pattern invariant, and provide a decent impedance match. They have low gain but if you do a link budget calculation, you'll see that your noise floor is like -110 dBm (I think... I forget but somewhere in that range).

The miracle that makes phones work is digital communications. Advanced modulation, extremely robust protocols, MIMO, etc have all contributed to ensuring communication even when the antenna on the phone itself is a terrible radiator (-5 dBi gain). If you do the link budget calculation to reach the nearest tower, you'd see that it works, so long as your link budget factors in all of the communication properties. That is, you have to consider what signal level the radio (cell phone) needs to demodulate the digital data and get information. Beyond analog gain (antenna, amplifiers, etc), you have digital gain through things like error-control coding (i.e. coding gain) and robust modulation techniques like OFDM (the standard for LTE and the future). Multiple access techniques (CDMA, TDMA), and MIMO also contribute to this. If you look at the "generation standards" like 3G and 4G, you'll see where on the protocol level things get super complicated. All of this goes into making cell networks work.

There's been a huge hiring thrust in the mobile industries to hire antenna engineers to design functioning antennas for thin phones. One of the toughest challenges facing folks now is that cell phones need many antennas that all couple and communicate on the same bands. So you have to be able to integrate multiple radios and antennas on a small platform and make sure everything works. When you don't do it right, you get the iPhone 4/4S... :-)

Comment: Shouldn't that be the "now-**in**famous iPhone 4 antenna"?

Answer (score 1):

Way back when antennas were long there was a shortage of cell towers and those that were there, were short. Nowadays frequencies have changed, cell towers have become more powerful (taller and more efficient) as well as the technology in the phones has increased.

Comment: Do you think it might have anything to do with the wavelengths of the signals used on the old and new systems?

Comment: Perhaps but I was thinking that since shorter wavelengths can't penetrate as much matter that they would be impractical for having a good reception. @Transistor

Comment: @Transistor No, not really. Modern cell phones can use many bands ranging from ~380 to 2600 MHz.

Answer (score 1):

Older cellphones mostly used traditional monopole antennas, which (basically) consist of a straight wire with specific length requirements (as stated by you).

Some modern cellphones use microstrip patch antennas. This type of antenna is obtained by strategically designing certain figures (like squares or others) and printing them on a printed circuit board (PCB), typically with a ground plane on the opposite face (See why this works [here](https://www.ukessays.com/essays/biology/basic-operation-principle-of-rectangular-microstrip-antenna-biology-essay.php)). This allows the antenna to be integrated with the rest of the cellphone's circuitry and to be fit inside the case.

The most common type of antenna in modern cellphones seems to be the planar inverted-F antenna (PIFA), which is a special type of monopole in a compact microstrip (patch) format.

Comment: This is not correct. Most modern phones use variants of inverted-F antennas. PIFAs are probably the most commonly found. Antenna-Theory does some analysis on older phones including the infamous iPhone 4. See: http://www.antenna-theory.com/antennas/aperture/ifa.php

Also, fractal antennas are nothing more than meandered current lines. Steven Best's famously rebutted the papers and showed that, while they work, they don't exhibit the miracles claimed by the fractal guys. They work because they're meandered lines...

Comment: @AntennaGuy I'll correct the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

> In modern cellphones all the antennas are inside the case

That's clearly not the case. The iphone for example is famously known for its visible antenna bands. The same for many others phones as well. Newer ones go to great length to hide their antenna bands making them less visible.